# Java JDBC - setCharacterStream() vs setBinaryStream(): What happens in the background differently?

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm currently learning Java JDBC: [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/blob.html)

When I use ...

preparedStatement.setCharacterStream(1, fileReader);

... instead of ...

preparedStatement.setBinaryStream(1, fileInputStream);

**What happens differently in the background?**

I mean: If I have an image-file then that file data consists out of 1 and 0. Right?

A text-file is the same at the very bottom. Some editor applies a character table on it and so it is finally transferred to a human readable text.

But on a low level it should be both the same.

So why this differentiation?

Isn't it just about reading / writing bits?